# PHP curl PUT does not continue respectively send payload/data

Tags: php, curl

I need to PUT some json data to an API endpoint, which works as expected via command line curl, but not via php curl and I don't have any idea, why it doesn't.

my command is

```
curl -v --insecure --request PUT --url <https://blabla/blablabla> --user 'username:password' --header 'Content-Type: application/json' --data '<valid json data>'
```

but it doesn't work this way within php:

```
  // get cURL resource
  $curl = curl_init();
  
  // set cURL options
  $curloptions = array(
    CURLOPT_PUT => true,                // set method to PUT
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,         // return the transfer as a string
    CURLOPT_VERBOSE => true,                // output verbose information
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => false,            // ignore self signed certificates
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,
    CURLOPT_USERNAME => $config['uag']['user'],     // set username
    CURLOPT_PASSWORD => $config['uag']['pass'],     // set password
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(            // set headers
      "Content-Type: application/json",
    ),
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $jsondata         // set data to post / put
    );
  curl_setopt_array($curl, $curloptions);

  foreach($serverurilist as $uri) {
    // set url
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $uri);
    // send the request and save response to $response
    $response = curl_exec($curl);

    // stop if fails
    if(!$response) {
      die('Error: "' . curl_error($curl) . '" - Code: ' . curl_errno($curl));
    }
    var_dump($response);
  }

  // close curl resource to free up system resources
  curl_close($curl);
```

What doesn't work? The payload / data doesn't get submitted. If I tcpdump the command line und php version without encryption, I can see, that the command line submits the data right after the **Expect: 100-continue** request and the **HTTP/1.1 100 Continue** response from the server. The php version doesn't do anything after the **HTTP/1.1 100 Continue** response and quits after reaching the timeout.

Answer (score 1):

From [documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php):

> **CURLOPT_PUT** - `true` to HTTP PUT a file. The file to PUT must be set with `CURLOPT_INFILE` and `CURLOPT_INFILESIZE`.

and you are not using any file to provide content.

You should use `CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'PUT'`.

---

This is your same cUrl request exported from Postman:

```php
$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => 'https://blabla/blablabla',
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
  CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'PUT',
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS =>'<valid json data>',
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => [
    'Content-Type: application/json',
    'Authorization: Basic dXNlcm5hbWU6cGFzc3dvcmQ='
  ],
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);

curl_close($curl);
echo $response;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use this `CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST=>'PUT'`

Comment: thanks, that was the "hidden" secret! :)